# Add a Custom link in Listing Screen Sonata Admin Bundle

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, sonata-admin

I am using sonata admin bundle. I have a company table and a product table. Each company can have many products. I am displaying the company table. What I want is that against each row of the company table, I need to place a link and when clicked it goes to the related product table. I am able to figure out how to show the related products. But I could not find out how to place a link along with each row of the company. Please help me on this. I googled and could find posts on how to place custom link in the dashboard which is not I need. Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out myself. You need to create a custom template and then add it as an action.

```
->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'floorplan' => array('template' => 'YourBundle:testLink.html.twig'),
            )
        ))
```

Comment: in which file exactly did you add this ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to generate a new template which does the job.

After that you have to set something like this at your listMapper config:

```
->add('yourLink', null, array('template' => '::testfield.html.twig'))
```

Look into the **SonataAdminBundle:Resource/CRUD/** folder where all list templates located.

For a string the *base_list_field.html.twig* gets rendered.

Comment: this one didnt work for me. I added template option as an action. I have posted my own answer. Thanks

Comment: In my case it works. But with the actions it's also good idea and it's smarter because you can add multiple custom links or buttons...

Comment: I have another question. Could you please help me? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958925/show-child-table-clickable-link-along-with-add-edit-screen-of-parent-table-sonat